# Need to join 3 tables that are the same

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

The title is a little confusing...

I have 3 tables that are identical.
One is for items within the last 2 weeks (named Picks), the second is an archive of that table for the current calendar year (named Archive), the third is an archive for previous year (named 2015).
All tables are identical except in name. There is only one field I need to return, "LoadRqst". It will only be populated in one of the 3 tables. If it is in the current 2 weeks, table 1, if the current year(older than 2 weeks), table 2 and last calendar year, table 3.  I have tried manipulating case statements until I'm blue in the face. I need to get the one that is populated and return it for display. Any help please?

```
SELECT s.recordid
    ,s.prodtime
    ,s.CharpyID
    ,r.STATUS
    ,sh.Load_Request_Num AS LoadNum
FROM (
    Reheat AS R INNER JOIN SawPieces AS S ON R.RecordID = S.RollRecID
    )
LEFT JOIN Shipping.RFDC.dbo.load_picks AS sh ON s.RecordID = sh.recordid
LEFT JOIN Shipping.RFDC_Archive.dbo.load_picks AS ar ON s.RecordID = ar.recordid
LEFT JOIN Shipping.RFDC_2015.dbo.load_picks AS arr ON s.RecordID = arr.recordid
WHERE DATEPART(YEAR, s.prodtime) <= '2017'
ORDER BY s.RecordID DESC
```

Comment: or provide whatever code you have till now for implementing this.

Comment: Hi @Obfuscated , welcome to SO or sort of ... What have you done ...?

Comment: Here is my starting query

Comment: select s.recordid, s.prodtime, s.CharpyID, r.Status, sh.Load_Request_Num as LoadNum
from (Reheat AS R INNER JOIN SawPieces AS S ON R.RecordID = S.RollRecID)
left join Shipping.RFDC.dbo.load_picks as sh on s.RecordID = sh.recordid
left join Shipping.RFDC_Archive.dbo.load_picks as ar on s.RecordID = ar.recordid
left join Shipping.RFDC_2015.dbo.load_picks as arr on s.RecordID = arr.recordid
WHERE DATEPART(YEAR, s.prodtime) <= '2017'
order by s.RecordID desc

Comment: Your query have nothing to do with what you described, can you explain more please. You said  you need to get the one that is populated and return it for display, are all your tables empty?

Comment: And why do you thing your query is not working?

Comment: I'm joining 2 table (Reheat & SawPieces). Then I need to add the "joined" (or however) return from the other 3 to get the load Rqst #. I need to add the rqst# to the return from the first 2 tables to complete the whole query. Clear as mud? LOL I know it's a little confusing, but I'm trying...be gentle with me.

Comment: It is working if I return all 3 rqst#'s. However, I only want the one that is populated, to be returned.

Comment: That is why I was manipulating the case statements, to only get the populated return.

Answer (score 0):

Instead `CASE WHEN` statements you can use `ISNULL` in SQL Server, also you can use `OUTER APPLY` instead of `LEFT JOIN`. Like this:

```
SELECT 
     s.recordid
    ,s.prodtime
    ,s.CharpyID
    ,r.STATUS
    ,ISNULL(a.lrn, ISNULL(b.lrn, c.lrn)) Load_Request_Num
FROM  Reheat r
      INNER JOIN SawPieces s ON r.RecordID = s.RollRecID    
      OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 Load_Request_Num lrn FROM Shipping.RFDC.dbo.load_picks sh WHERE s.RecordID = sh.recordid)  a
      OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 Load_Request_Num lrn FROM Shipping.RFDC_Archive.dbo.load_picks ar WHERE s.RecordID = ar.recordid) b
      OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 Load_Request_Num lrn FROM Shipping.RFDC_2015.dbo.load_picks arr WHERE s.RecordID = arr.recordid) c
WHERE DATEPART(YEAR, s.prodtime) <= '2017'
ORDER BY s.RecordID DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, the table `SawPieces` has a column `ProdTime`. If the year of the date for a given row is `2015`, then you'll want to join that row with it's matching row in the `2015` archive table. If the date is from the last 2 weeks, you'll want to join the row with it's matching row in the last 2 weeks table, and if it's from the current calendar year, match it with it's corresponding row in the current year archive table.

I would classify the rows from `SawPieces` in order to join the minimum amount of rows with each table (the final result should be the same as without filtering, but the set of rows to analyze should be considerably lower.

eg

```
SELECT u.RecordId, u.ProdTime, u.CharpyId, u.LoadNum, r.Status FROM
(
    (
        (SELCT s.RecordId, s.ProdTime, s.CharpyId, a.Load_Request_Num AS LoadNum
         FROM SawPieces AS s
         INNER JOIN Shipping.RFDC.dbo.load_picks AS a
         ON s.RecordId = a.RecordId
         WHERE s.ProdTime BETWEEN DATEADD(week, -2, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE())
        UNION ALL
        (SELCT s.RecordId, s.ProdTime, s.CharpyId, a.Load_Request_Num AS LoadNum
         FROM SawPieces AS s
         INNER JOIN Shipping.RFDC_Archive.dbo.load_picks AS a
         ON s.RecordId = a.RecordId
         WHERE YEAR(s.ProdTime) > 2015 AND s.ProdTime < DATEADD(week, -2, GETDATE()))
        UNION ALL
        (SELCT s.RecordId, s.ProdTime, s.CharpyId, a.Load_Request_Num AS LoadNum
         FROM SawPieces AS s
         INNER JOIN Shipping.RFDC_2015.dbo.load_picks AS a
         ON s.RecordId = a.RecordId
         WHERE YEAR(s.ProdTime) = 2015)
    ) AS u
    INNER JOIN
    Reheat AS r
    ON u.RecordId = r.RecordId
);
```

Haven't tested this myself, so there could be minor syntax issues pending to fix before the query can be executed.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

Here's what I ended up doing...
Since they are all numbers (but in a varchar field ??? ) I ended up with...

```
 , sum(ISNULL(convert(int,sh.Load_Request_Num),'0') + ISNULL(convert(int,ar.Load_Request_Num),'0') + ISNULL(convert(int,arr.Load_Request_Num),'0')) as loadNum
```

Converting them to int. then summing since only one will be populated. Not the prettiest fix, but it works.

Thanks for your answers though, still the best place to go for someone elses thoughts and help.

Comment: Why not `ISNULL(sh.Load_Request_Num, ISNULL(ar.Load_Request_Num, arr.Load_Request_Num))` ?